# Create an Activity / Workflow explorer in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access

Is it possible to create an activity explorer in Sharepoint 2010?

By activity explorer I refer to the functionality of logging emails, phone calls, documents accessed (and time and who accessed/edited them) to specific entries in a database.

For example, I intend to export my current Access Claims Management database top a Sharepoint sever. 
With each claim entered into the database:

- I wish to log all relevant emails sent, and the user logs all relevant calls. This would require sending emails through the sharepoint front end I pressume?
- For each claim a directory is created, where the user can store relevant documents to each claim. Is it possible to log / version control these documents?

Thanks in advance for any assistance or advice.

Noel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answers:

-I wish to log all relevant emails sent, and the user logs all relevant calls. This would require sending emails through the sharepoint front end I pressume?
Yes, otherwise you would not be able to track them.

-For each claim a directory is created, where the user can store relevant documents to each claim. Is it possible to log / version control these documents?
Yes, you could employ a document library that creates folders automatically when an email arrives. Or you can pre-create and then any email sent to the document library will be displayed as a SharePoint item. You can enable versioning on any SharePoint list/document library.

You could then build an custom activity explorer that will display all these actions.

Comment: Cheers @RoManiac, so this all possible through sharepoint. Have you any advice or staring points as to creating a custom activity explorer?

Comment: The activity explorer can be similar to a report with all the actions that occurred. If CQWP is not enough you will have to dive into code. http://www.sharepointbriefing.com/features/article.php/3874226/Content-Query-Web-Part-SharePoints-Swiss-Army-Knife.htm